# Angular 2 Material - Use md-color in component code

Tags: angular2-material

I have a situation where I want to dynamically set the color and darkness/lightness of elements in my component, the same way I would with md-color(). Is there any way of doing this or should I hard code my theme colors into my component code?

Here's the hard-coded way:

```
if(val.className === "negative"){
    if(val.p < .25){
        color = "#b0bec5";
    } else if ( val.p < .75){
        color = "#78909c";
    } else{
        color = "#546e7a";
    }
} else if(val.className === "positive"){
    if(val.p < .25){
        color = "#f48fb1";
    } else if ( val.p < .75){
        color = "#ec407a";
    } else{
        color = "#d81b60";
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is:

```
if(val.className === "negative"){
    color = accent;
else {
    color = primary;
}
darkness = val.p * 800;
return md-color(color,darkness);
```